# How to find first occurence of particular text within element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest for inserting some element in first position of the particular text within particular element.

In the given sample, required to identify the text 'text1' found as first position, then need to insert <first/> after 'text1'. Please suggest.

**XML:**

```
<article>
    <body>
        <list>text1 text2</list>
        <para>The text1 text3 text4</para>
        <para>The text1 text1 text5</para>
        <para>They text1 text1 text1</para>
        <para>The ttext3 ext1 text1</para>
        <para>The <i>text1</i> <u>text1</u></para>
        <para>The <b>text1</b> <b>text1</b></para>
        <para>The text1</para>
        <para>The text2</para>
    </body>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para//text()">
        <xsl:variable name="varText1" select="'text1'"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., $varText1)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()=1"><xsl:value-of select="."/><first/></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required output:**

```
<article>
    <body>
        <list>text1 text2</list>
        <para>The text1<first/> text3 text4</para>
        <para>The text1<first/> text1 text5</para>
        <para>They text1<first/> text1 text1</para>
        <para>The ttext3 ext1 text1<first/></para>
        <para>The <i>text1<first/></i> <u>text1</u></para>
        <para>The <b>text1<first/></b> <b>text1</b></para>
        <para>The text1<first/></para>
        <para>The text2</para>
    </body>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of this problem is to identify the *first* descendant text node in each `para` that contains "text1".  Once that node is identified it's a simple matter of `substring-before` and `substring-after`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[. is (ancestor::para[1]//text()[contains(., 'text1')])[1]]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'text1')" />
        <xsl:text>text1</xsl:text>
        <first/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'text1')" />            
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, working perfectly, as required, plus one. Nice Xpath code.

Comment: Sir, one request, what is the meaning of "xsl:template match="text()[. is ". Please suggest the '.is' facility.

Comment: @RudramuniTP [the `is` operator in XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-node-comparisons) tests whether its two arguments are _the same node_, as opposed to `=` or `eq` which would just check whether the arguments have the _same value_.

Comment: @RudramuniTP if you were limited to XSLT 1.0 then you'd have to use the `generate-id` function to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will try as suggested.